# What is the advantage of using threading in program?

Tags: c#

Am newbie to thread concept. I have little confusion over thread.

What is the difference between normally calling the method and calling the method using threading.  What is the use of thread.join?

Example:
In the code behind file: normally calling the method

```
Getdata();
```

By using thread am calling this methd:

```
Thread th=new Thread(new ThreadStart(Getdata));

th.Start();
```

Which one yields high performance

Comment: I would say it depends on the program, sometimes it is not necessary to use threading as the program itself doesn't require it, but sometimes it really helps especially when it comes to work with GUIs, threading allows the user to perform actions while working on certain thing. And all in all I would say it is much to say in here, too much I guess.

Comment: I dont know about your GetData() but if you can split GetData for let's say two parts, then you could use threading to get it faster. You can run two threads, first get one part of data and second get rest.

Comment: @Tomq What is the use of thread.Join when am running several threads

Comment: With threading, you can do something while the GetData() call runs. I.e. you could offer a Cancel button or display a progress bar. If you call GetData synchronously, you'll have to wait until it finishes and your UI will be blocked for that time. Of course, threading makes things more complex, as you have to check when the result is available and so on. I agree to Tafari that threading is a very complex topic and cannot be told in a few sentences.

Comment: @user2918543: Thread.Join() waits for the thread to end. Depending on how your GetData() function works, you'll have to wait for it to end to get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main reason to have more than one thread is to speed up calculations. Each thread would perform one part of complex calculation, on one part of input data. If you have as many threads as there are processor cores each thread will run freely, and number of calculations per second will increase. Increasing the number of threads above this point (number of cores) will not give much benefit. Care must be taken about other parts of processor architecture (memory, processor cache, some other shared resource) so that it does not become a bottleneck and force all the threads to wait on it most of the time.

Second reason to have threads is to remove all lengthy operations away from main thread, which is usually GUI thread. Application is then more user friendly, and user will not experience window "freeze".

Third reason to have threads is to make the code both a little bit faster and simpler at the same time. Let's say you have a complex operation with your data and with shared resources (web service, database, some specialized hardware, printer), and the complex operation can be separated in several simpler operations, and parts of the operation are omitted depending on the data. You could have a "pipeline" of threads, where each thread does one simple stuff with the data, has an exclusive access to some resource, and sends the result to other thread in the pipeline. Overall process would run faster than if you would have only one thread that runs every bit data from start to the end, but the code would also not be too much complex.

Answer (score 1):

By using threading you are able to let slow-running processes run "besides" the rest of your code.

With Join you are waiting for that code to complete.

Say for example that you are getting data over the network from 3 different slow servers. Then it's a good idea to launch tree threads getting this data and then joining on them before you do the calculation. In that way you are able to start the calculation when the slowest server has responded instead of the combined time of all three servers.

Regarding performance, you proably have a multi-core machine. By threading out you are able to utilize more cores, so you get better performance also.

Answer (score 1):

Lets boil this down to a simple case. You have a dual core processor in your computer. Lets say each core can only process one thread at a time (in reality, they can switch between many, very quickly).

In order to run two pieces of code at once, you would need 2 threads. If you simply appended the code from the 2nd thread to the end of the first, the 2nd thread would have to wait for the 1st thread's code to complete. Thread 1 is said to be *blocking*. Thread 2 is said to be *waiting*.

Threads have great application. Consider games, where the rendering of the scene is performed in a loop. Any heavy processing between each frame will cause the frame-rate to slow down. You want to avoid this. What do you do? You do your heavy processing on another thread and trust that the operating system will make the best use of the available CPU cores.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of threading is to fulfill the need to run separate code in the same time. In general, if you have a source-code, all the lines in your source-code will be executed sequentially. Let's consider the case when you are sending an email to 20 receipients. If you send all the mails one after the other, then the total waiting time is the total time while your emails are delivered. If you create 20 threads, one for each email sending, then your waiting time will be roughly the time of your slowest mail, that's approximately 20x speedup. Also, let's consider you are playing a chess game against the computer. The engine has to constantly think about the best possible variation, but in the meantime its time is decreasing and it must be displayed graphically, also, sometimes sound effects should be displayed and so on.