# Benefits of a multi thread program in a unicore system

Tags: c++, multithreading, processor

My professor causally mentioned that we should program multi-thread programs even if we are using a unicore processor however because of the lack of time , he did not elaborate on  it .

**I would like to know what are the benefits of a multi-thread program in a unicore processor ??**

Comment: The same ones as a multi-threaded program on a multi-core processor.  It is the job of the operating system to make it *look* like the machine has as many processors as there are threads.  If you use threads to squeeze more cpu cycles out of the machine then you are not ahead on a single core machine.

Comment: More answers here: [What is the advantage of using threading in program?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19652554/395718)

Comment: Look at the accepted answer and the (second) last comment of How can multithreading speed up an application (when threads can't run concurrently)?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate because it asks which are the benefits in general, not performance-wise. +1 to question

Answer (score 2):

Some applications *need* to be multi-threaded. Multi-threading isn't just about improving performance by using more cores, it's also about performing multiple tasks at once.

Take Skype for example - The GUI needs to be able to accept the text you're entering, display it on the screen, listen for new messages coming from the user you're talking to, and display them. This wouldn't be a trivial task in a single threaded application.

Even if there's only one core available, the OS thread scheduler will give you the illusion of parallelism.

Comment: Your example of Skype is not completely correct. It's quite possible to handle all the things you mentioned serially. It's just far more simple to have threads doing separate things separately.

Comment: @arne I guess it could be done serially, but not efficiently. You'd have to stop listening on a socket, to start processing GUI events, and keep going back and forth.

Comment: Well, you could check the socket for data via `select`, same with GUI interaction. But that would be quite painful. Whether it's less efficient is not so obvious.

Comment: Actually, doing an app like skype efficiently in a single-threaded program is not that hard if you program asynchronously. Of course only if all blocking operations can be replaced by some polling mechanism (otherwise you'd need threads to wrap that).

Comment: There is also coroutine which give you the illusion of a multi-threaded progam when it's actually just single threaded.

Answer (score 2):

It won't be as significant as a multi-core system but it can still provide some benefits.

Mainly all the benefits that you are going to get will be regarding to the context switch that will happen after a input miss to the already executing thread. Executing thread may be waiting for anything such as a hardware resource or a branch mis-prediction or even data transfer after a cache miss.

At this point the waiting thread can be executed to benefit from this "waiting time". But of course context switch will take some time. Also managing threads inside the code rather than sequential computation can create some extra complexity to your program. And as it has been said, some applications needs to be multi-threaded so there is no escape from the context switch in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is about not blocking. Running many threads on a single core still gives the illusion of concurrency. So you can have, say, a thread doing IO while another one does user interactions. The user interaction thread is not blocked while the other does IO, so the user is free to carry on interacting.

Answer (score 1):

Benefits could be different.
One of the widely used examples is the application with GUI, which supposed to perform some kind of computations. If you will have a single thread - the user will have to wait the result before dealing something else with the application, but if you start it in the separate thread - user interface could be still available for user during the computation process. So, multi-thread program could emulate multi-task environment even on a unicore system. That's one of the points.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already mentioned, not blocking is one application. Another one is separation of logic for unrelated tasks that are to be executed simultaneously. Using threads for that leaves handling of scheduling these tasks to the OS.

However, note that it may also be possible to implement similar behavior using asynchronous operations in a single thread. "Future" and boost::asio provide ways of doing non-blocking stuff without necessarily resorting to multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends a bit on how exactly you design your threads and which logic is actually in the thread. Some benefits you can even get on a single core:

- A thread can wrap a blocking/long-during call you can't circumvent otherwise. For some operations there are polling mechanisms, but not for all.
- A thread can wrap an almost standalone part of your application that has virtually no interaction with other code. For example background polling for updates, monitoring some resource (e.g. free storage), checking internet connectivity. If you keep them in a separate thread you can keep the code relatively simple in its own 'runtime' without caring too much about the impact on the main program, the sole communication with the main logic is usually a single 'event'.
- In some environments you might get more processing time. This mainly depends on how your OS scheduling system works, but if this allocates time per thread, the more threads you have the more your app will be scheduled.

Some benefits long-term:

- Where it's not hard to do you benefit if your hardware evolves. You never know what's going to happen, today your app runs on a single-core embedded device, tomorrow that embedded device gets a quad core. Programming threaded from the beginning improves your future scalability.
- One example is an environment where you can deterministically assign work to a thread, e.g. based on some hash all related operations end up in the same thread. The advantage for single cores is 'small' but it's not hard to do as you need little synchronization primitives so the overhead stays small.

That said, I think there are situations where it's very ill advise:

- As soon as your required synchronization mechanism with other threads becomes complex (e.g. multiple locks, lots of critical sections, ...). It might still be then that multi-threading gives you a benefit when effectively moving to multiple CPUs, but the overhead is huge both for your single core and your programming time.

Answer (score 0):

For instance think about operations that block because of slow peripheral devices (harddisk access etc.). While these are waiting, even the single core can do other things asyncronously.

Answer (score 0):

In a lot of applications the bottleneck is not CPU processing power. So when the program flow is waiting for completion of IO requests (user input, network/disk IO), critical resources to be available, or any sort of asynchroneously triggered events, the CPU can be scheduled to do other work instead of just blocking.

In this case you don't necessarily need multiple threads that can actually run in parallel. Cooperative multi-tasking concepts like [asynchroneous IO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O), [coroutines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine), or [fibers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_%28computer_science%29) come into mind.

If however the application's bottleneck is CPU processing power (constantly 100% CPU usage), then it makes sense to increase the number of CPUs available to the application. At that point it is easier to scale the application up to use more CPUs if it was designed to run in parallel upfront.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, one answer was not yet given:

You **will** have to write multithreaded applications in the future!

The average number of cores will double every 18 months in the future. People have learned single-threaded programming for 50 years now, and now they are confronted with devices that have multiple cores. The programming style in a multi-threaded environment differs significantly from single-threaded programming. This refers to low-level aspects like avoiding race conditions and proper synchronization, as well as the high-level aspects like the general algorithm design.

So in addition to the points already mentioned, it's also about writing future-proof software, scalability and the development of the skills that are required to achieve these goals.